# Stop Java Coffee Cup icon from appearing in the Dock on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, dock

After upgrading to OSX 10.8.4, background Java processes started placing a Java Cup icon in the Dock.  It causes the currently active window to loose focus which is very annoying when running some script that forks many short running Java processes (headless).  The file menu (top of the screen next to the apple symbol will show the name of the class file that Java is running, e.g. org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar).

Since I'm not explicitly launching these Java commands, I've tried putting
alias java="java -Djava.awt.headless=true" 
in .profile but this doesn't seem to help.

Has anyone run into this and know how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: see comment on my answer

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Like @EGHM said, it's `-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true`, but with **no quotes**. At least it works for me (OS X 10.7.5).

If you happen to be using Eclipse, you can add this JVM argument globally in Preferences → Installed JREs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I want to add that in OS X 10.10.4 it worked for me as well using: `System.setPropery("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");` as first statement in my `main()`.

Comment: This worked for me, but only for a few days :( The icon has now again started showing up in the dock. Any ideas?

Comment: ... and that happened on Mac OS 10.11.6 as well. Something triggered from gradle on an android project, needed `-Djava.awt.headless=true` alone didn't fix it all, `-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true` as well.

Comment: @FilipeEsperandio this seems to be gradle daemon process icon and has nothing in common with original question. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201742

Answer (score 17):

Like @EHGM and @Nelson pointed out, `-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true` needs to be added as an argument to the JVM.

You can set it globally for all java applications launched from the command line (or a shell) by adding it to the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable.

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true"
```

You could add the export statement to your `$HOME/.bashrc` or whatever startup script relevant to the shell you're using.

Answer (score 9):

Try -Dapple.awt.UIElement="true"

Comment: @Eugene Actually you noted -Djava.awt.headless=true I'm suggesting -Dapple.awt.UIElement="true" please note UIElement and quotes around true.

Answer (score 6):

You can also put the statement into the project-level or global `gradle.properties` file

```
systemProp.apple.awt.UIElement=true
```

Comment: 老哥稳啊，太tm的感谢了！ it works for me ! Android Studio 2.3.3 + macOS 10.12.5