# Hiding install4j generated service from dock in OS X

Tags: java, macos, install4j, dock

I am creating an OS X installer for our Java app using Install4j. The installer successfully installs and launches our daemon service. However it shows up in the dock with the default Java icon and the text "Launcher". How do we hide it from the dock?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that this had nothing to do with Install4j. This answer had the solution: [Stop Java Coffee Cup icon from appearing in the Dock on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460777/stop-java-coffee-cup-icon-from-appearing-in-doc-on-mac-osx)