# A way to hide the java icon from mac's menubar?

Tags: java, macos

I am trying make make a process java program, and it is going just fine. The problem is that it create a java icon, even if there's nothing to show. I tried to use the "Dapple.awt.UIElement=true" or "Djava.awt.headless=true", But truth is: I do not know how to implement those since i'm not that mac friendly... Any help would be great!

Comment: It's possible this has changed, but you could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246766/how-to-hide-the-java-swt-program-icon-in-the-dock-when-the-application-is-in-the) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460777/stop-java-coffee-cup-icon-from-appearing-in-the-dock-on-mac-osx). As of Java 7 some of the JVM properties may no longer be supported

Comment: The mac I am using is java 1.6, so it should be fine...?

Comment: I have looked at those post before writing my question, And I still don't know how to use those

Comment: If you're using java 6 you "should" be able to use the JVM arguments, but, if you're running the jar/program directly, then you need to set this up yourself, typically through a shell script, for example

Answer (score 1):

In your Java code, in `main()`, add this:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

It's unclear what you mean by:

> "Djava.awt.headless=true"

The "D" is used to set properties at the command-line.  For example:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar myProg.jar
```