# Hide Gradle daemon's Java icon on macOS dock when using Intellij?

Tags: java, macos, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm new to Intellij, macOS, and gradle, and would like to hide the Java icons from the macOS dock associated the gradle daemon processes. Setting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460777/stop-java-coffee-cup-icon-from-appearing-in-the-dock-on-mac-osx)) in my zshenv (similar to bashrc or bash_profile) is sufficient when running from the command line, but does not work when running the build from Intellij.

I also tried setting the daemon flags using [`org.gradle.jvmargs`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) with the same flag (`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true`) in my home gradle.properties file, but all `-D` flags are somehow stripped out (regardless of whether or not it's being run from the terminal or from Intellij, which seems like its own issue, [given that you should be able to set `-D` flags with this parameter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory)), and thus has no effect.

Surely there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: `is sufficient when running from the command line` - how do you run from command line? And how do you run it from IDE?

Comment: in the command line, simply `./gradlew task`; in the IDE, I click the build icon (the hammer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the property like `systemProp.apple.awt.UIElement=true` in `gradle.properties` file in project root directory should work.

Comment: Could you be a bit more analytic on how to do this? I can't seem to find a `gradle.properties` in my filesystem.